# SORM class cast exception

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sorm

I'm trying to migrate my Play framework app from slick to SORM. Created basic classes, but cannot get it working.

```
case class UserAction(url: String, request: Map[String,String], ts: DateTime)

val ts = DateTime.now()
val act = Db.save(UserAction(request.uri, request.headers.toSimpleMap, ts))
```

But getting following exception:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[ClassCastException: __wrapper$1$cf01f4410488416a9990d12622889a84.__wrapper$1$cf01f4410488416a9990d12622889a84$PersistedAnonymous31$1 cannot be cast to models.sorm.UserAction]]
at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: __wrapper$1$cf01f4410488416a9990d12622889a84.__wrapper$1$cf01f4410488416a9990d12622889a84$PersistedAnonymous31$1 cannot be cast to models.sorm.UserAction
at Global$$anonfun$doFilter$1.apply(Global.scala:21) ~[classes/:na]
at Global$$anonfun$doFilter$1.apply(Global.scala:15) ~[classes/:na]
at play.api.mvc.EssentialAction$$anon$2.apply(Action.scala:61) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
at play.api.mvc.EssentialAction$$anon$2.apply(Action.scala:60) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$12.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:162) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$12.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:160) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: 1. Make sure that you're using Sorm of at least the version 0.3.10. 2. The provided code is not enough to reproduce the issue. As the stack trace suggests, there's something happening that triggers the error in _Global.scala_. I'm gonna need to see the code from that file.

Comment: Thanks for helping me!
I've initially posted this line 21 from Global.scala, but here's full file http://pastebin.com/a4MxSv4i
And for reference here's Db.scala 
http://pastebin.com/mDDmD2Kk

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with your code. Looks like, it is an issue related to an update of classloader, which is triggered by Play. An 0.3.10 SORM release contained some related updates, that's why it would help if you tested this with both 0.3.10 and 0.3.9. Furthermore, I suggest to move this discussion to SORM's issue tracker, where I've already opened [a related ticket](https://github.com/sorm/sorm/issues/31).